# sum of filtered value in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I've set up my normal filters in my worksheet as I want them displayed. The main field I'm using is `call_duration`. I have `SUM(call_duration)`, and `AVG(call_duration)`. I would also like the SUM and COUNT of call_duration where the individual values of call_duration are over 300.

I've tried to go into the value to filter it but it just brings up the SUM values, not the individual values. I'm not sure what this would be in a calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to change the pill on the filter shelf from measure to dimension. If you already have the sum(call_duration) on the filter shelf, right click and choose the Dimension option. This will open the filter dialog box. Choose the At Least screen. Put in the value of 301.

The other option is to make it a discrete dimension on the filter shelf (right click, choose Dimension, then right-click again and choose Discrete). Then on the Condition tab of the filter dialog, write in the formula `[call_duration] >= 300`.